# Error when trying to run bashrc

Tags: ubuntu

Hi I'm trying to install hadoop in ubuntu. As a step, I need to run the bashrc file using the following command

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

But this gives me the error,

bash: //path:No such file or directory

Is anyone know the reason for this

Comment: I bet that's not the real error message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the correct path for Java:
`#export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")`
As said in Hadoop documentation.